# Using Leafletjs and GeoJSON?

Tags: leaflet, geojson

I am new to Leafletjs and I am trying to figure out how to plot a polyline on a map using a geoJson object. I've gotten as far as getting a map, making it centered on a given lat/long and setting the zoom. However, I cannot determine how to display the lines using geoJson data.

I confirmed that the coordinates work - I was able to plot them using the Leaflet polyline layer.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Leaflet GeoJSON Example</title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="leaflet.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map" style="width: 900px; height: 700px"></div>
    <script src="leaflet.js"></script>
    <script>
        var center = [42.454873, -71.125094];
        var map = L.map('map').setView(center, 15);
        L.tileLayer('http://otile1.mqcdn.com/tiles/1.0.0/map/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>contributors'}).addTo(map);

        var myLines = [{
            "type": "LineString",
            "coordinates": [[42.438917, -71.116146],[42.443904, -71.122044]]
        }, {
            "type": "LineString",
            "coordinates": [[42.447298, -71.121447],[42.454873, -71.125094],[42.459079, -71.124988]]
        }];

        var myStyle = {
            "color": "#ff7800",
            "weight": 5,
            "opacity": 0.65
        };

        L.geoJson(myLines, {style: myStyle}).addTo(map);

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

In your code, myLines is not a geojson structure ...

Try with this syntax

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {},
      "geometry": {
        "type": "LineString",
        "coordinates": [[42.438917, -71.116146],[42.443904, -71.122044]]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {},
      "geometry": {
        "type": "LineString",
        "coordinates": [[42.447298, -71.121447],[42.454873, -71.125094],[42.459079, -71.124988]]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

To write proper geojson you can use: http://geojson.io/

Comment: nice link. will have to use that. i've found http://jsonlint.com/ to also be helpful in pointing out syntax errors.